# Is there supposed to be "iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat" before an exit 0 statement?

Tags: raspberry-pi, exit-code, access-point

I am trying to set up an access point via Raspberry Pi 2 and a USB WiFi adapter AWUS036H, made by Alfa Network. I am following a [guide](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/setting-up-wireless-access-point-using-raspberry-pi). The guide is not clear on step 9 whether or not "iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat" (no quotes) is supposed to be before exit=0 on the same line or above it. It may or may not be the single faulty line of code in the system.

I have tried twice, although I may know something else that could have messed it up the two other times. I will try once more the day of this post. I will try a different guide if this try doesn't work. Clarification on the exit 0 statement is crucial. (P.S. I am *really* new to anything in the coding/developing/terminal world. Forgive my ignorance if I need clarification on your answers.)

Answer (score 0):

Having looked at the linked document, I find that in Step 9 it says (in part):

"...and add the following lines at the bottom of the system, just before the exit 0 statement"

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

My interpretation of this is that the text shown above should be on its own line, immediately followed by the line containing the "exit 0" statement.